HLF operator peer pod not creating issue
I am creating a hyperledger fabric network with hlf operator(version 1.8.0).
here i am getting an issue of peer not getting created when i hit this command
kubectl hlf peer create --statedb=couchdb --image=$PEER_IMAGE --version=$PEER_VERSION --storage-class=standard --enroll-id=peer --mspid=Org1MSP --enroll-pw=peerpw --capacity=5Gi --name=org1-peer0 --ca-name=org1-ca.default --hosts=peer0-org1.localho.st --istio-port=443

Command Response:
    W0424 16:57:19.873261 1617150 warnings.go:70] unknown field "spec.deliveryClientaddressOverrides"
    W0424 16:57:19.873290 1617150 warnings.go:70] unknown field "spec.gatewayApi"
    W0424 16:57:19.873301 1617150 warnings.go:70] unknown field "spec.gossip.aliveExpirationTimeout"
    W0424 16:57:19.873308 1617150 warnings.go:70] unknown field "spec.gossip.aliveTimeInterval"
    W0424 16:57:19.873316 1617150 warnings.go:70] unknown field "spec.gossip.reconnectInterval"
    W0424 16:57:19.873328 1617150 warnings.go:70] unknown field "spec.gossip.responseWaitTime"
    W0424 16:57:19.873336 1617150 warnings.go:70] unknown field "spec.peerVolumeMounts"
    W0424 16:57:19.873343 1617150 warnings.go:70] unknown field "spec.podAnnotations"
    W0424 16:57:19.873369 1617150 warnings.go:70] unknown field "spec.podLabels"
    W0424 16:57:19.873377 1617150 warnings.go:70] unknown field "spec.secret.enrollment.component.catls.secretRef"
    W0424 16:57:19.873389 1617150 warnings.go:70] unknown field "spec.secret.enrollment.component.external"
    W0424 16:57:19.873395 1617150 warnings.go:70] unknown field "spec.secret.enrollment.tls.catls.secretRef"
    W0424 16:57:19.873401 1617150 warnings.go:70] unknown field "spec.secret.enrollment.tls.external"
    W0424 16:57:19.873407 1617150 warnings.go:70] unknown field "spec.traefik"
    W0424 16:57:19.873413 1617150 warnings.go:70] unknown field "spec.volumes"
    INFO[0006] Peer org1-peer0 created on namespace default

But the service is getting created
here are the logs from hlf controller manager pod
    1.713958009311906e+09   ERROR   controllers.FabricPeer  k8sAPIClientError failed to update the application status   {"error": "Operation cannot be fulfilled on fabricpeers.hlf.kungfusoftware.es \"org1-peer0\": the object has been modified; please apply your changes to the latest version and try again"}
github.com/kfsoftware/hlf-operator/controllers/peer.(*FabricPeerReconciler).Reconcile
    github.com/kfsoftware/hlf-operator/controllers/peer/peer_controller.go:485
sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/controller.(*Controller).Reconcile
    sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.12.3/pkg/internal/controller/controller.go:121
sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/controller.(*Controller).reconcileHandler
    sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.12.3/pkg/internal/controller/controller.go:320
sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/controller.(*Controller).processNextWorkItem
    sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.12.3/pkg/internal/controller/controller.go:273
sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/controller.(*Controller).Start.func2.2

this is reponse from the command for registering user for peer in ca
❯ kubectl hlf ca register --name=org1-ca --user=peer --secret=peerpw --type=peer \
 --enroll-id enroll --enroll-secret=enrollpw --mspid Org1MSP

    Error: Response from server: Error Code: 74 - Identity 'peer' is already registered


